# The Bernoulli Equation - I think there is a mistake in my book...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So the Bernoulli equation is a differential equation of the form $$y' + p(x)y = q(x){y^n}$$

That is fine but my book says if you make the change of variable $u = {y^{1 - n}}$ then you get $u' + (1 - n)p(x)u = (1 - n)q(x)$ but that doesn't seem right. If it is, why can't I get it when I substitute $u = {y^{1 - n}}$?

Comment: Substituting $u = y^{1-n}$ into $u' + (1-n) p(x) u = (1-n) q(x)$ gives $(1-n) y^{-n} y' + (1-n)p(x) y^{1-n} = (1-n) q(x)$ which becomes $y' + p(x) y = q(x) y^n$ after dividing by $(1-n) y^{-n}$. So, I don't know why you don't get the same equations :)

Comment: Your book's equation appears to be correct.  [this webpage](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx) may be useful for you.  It's difficult to say where your mistake was without seeing your work.

Answer (score 1):

We know $y = u^{\frac{1}{1-n}}$, so $y' = \frac{1}{1-n} u^{\frac{1}{1-n} - 1} u' = \frac{1}{1-n} u^{\frac{n}{1-n}}$

Plug in the equation:
$$\frac{1}{1-n} u^{\frac{n}{1-n}} + p(x) u^{\frac{1}{1-n}} = q(x) (u^{\frac{1}{1-n}})^n$$

After simplification, the result arrives.